# Kotlin understanding missing var keyword in for loop

Tags: kotlin

I am a beginner in Kotlin and going through for loop

Simple code sample:

```
 for (i in 1..5) print(i)
```

Please can someone advise me why we do not specify the counter/iterator variable type "i" with the keyword var / val. Since "var /val" is the standard way to declare variables in Kotlin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply how the `for` loop syntax is designed. I cannot speak for the designers, but I believe that's a design decision to avoid unnecessary bloat, and maybe confusion.

You cannot use an existing variable as the loop variable. The loop variable is scoped to the loop, and shadows existing ones from outer scopes. So it's kind of implied that you're declaring a new variable here, even without a keyword (however I have to admit that the shadowing behaviour would be clearer if we had to write the `val`/`var` keyword here).

Also, the loop variable is actually a `val` inside the loop's body (it cannot be reassigned), but it can feel like a `var` because it changes for each loop turn and is technically declared outside the loop's body. In effect, it's like a new `val` declared in the loop's body with a new value for each loop iteration.

So your example code can be thought of as:

```kotlin
var temp = 1
while (temp <= 5) {
    val i = temp
    println(i)
    temp++
}
```

That's probably why the designers decided to not put any keyword here: it's unnecessary, and both `val` and `var` would be confusing in their own way.

Comment: actually, the loop variable is **always** `val`, not `var`, as you can see [here](https://i.ibb.co/b2gD5SD/kotlin-for-loop-val.png)

Comment: Maybe that’s why they leaned towards not having you put `val` or `var`. It’s not exactly a `var` because it behaves like a `val` that’s redeclared for each iteration of the loop, so its scope is local inside the enclosure even though it is named outside the enclosure.

Comment: @MichaelPfaff right, what I wrote is a bit misleading, I'll clarify that bit. I agree with Tenfour04, it's kinda neither one nor the other. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I have always seen these variables as just regular `val`. Remember that `for` is based on iterators, so it is really expanded to: `val iter = list.iterator(); while (iter.hasNext()) { val item = iter.next() }` - `item` variable does not really exist outside the loop body. Iterating over ranges is one exception, because it uses counters, but this is just a compiler optimization. Conceptually `for` is iterating over something.

Comment: @broot Yes, I didn't mean to account for the actual desugaring of the loop, but rather to point out that conceptually it is as if there is something `var` that lives for the whole loop and something `val` that's scoped to a single interation.

Comment: The compiler will give you a warning in case of "shadowing behavior"

Comment: @МихаилНафталь the code is not always read in an IDE, especially during code reviews. But in any case this is not a big deal of course, I never had to read code with shadowing personally